# Changes to WordPress theme's "woocommerce.css" file not working?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using the WordPress theme ShopIsle, and I have made a change to the woocommerce.css file (wp-content/themes/shop-isle/inc/woocommerce/css/woocommerce.css). However, this change is having no affect. I have a feeling that an identical file is located somewhere else, and I will have to edit this file as well... how do I make sure my changes are being saved?

When I go back onto the file that I edited, it does save the changes but the changes are having no affect, and when I inspect element it shows me the original, un-edited code. How do I fix this?

Comment: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/css/woocommerce.css cheked here?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman yes, however I could not find the line of code I am trying to edit within this file.

Comment: Are you using caching plugins? if yes please clear the cache and try

Comment: You should inspect element for which you have applied css adjustments, and check if there are properties above your changes that have higher priority. Also, do the hard reload in browser, or check changes in incognito browsing. Also, try to change the version of included .css file.